# Laravel 5.4 - Use the model instantiated from Controller in a View Composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So lets say I have a view for a single project and in that view I have a form (uses a component) that opens up in a model. In order for that model component to even appear, I need that instance of the project. So for example

The route in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/projects/{project}', 'ProjectController@show');
```

My Project Controller

```
/* ProjectController show() method */
public function show(Project $project)
{
  return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
}
```

In my show blade template for that project, I have the following component to add a vendor to a project. As you can see I need to pass the instance of the project to that component.

```
@component('layouts.modals.add-project-vendor', ['project' => $project])

@endcomponent
```

I know you can attach data to a component, view, etc. using a view composer. I am utilizing the view composers throughout my project but I am gathering the data within the composer. What I want to be able to do is just use the instance of that project without even having to actually pass the project to the components. So for example.

```
View::composer(
   ['layouts.modals.add-project-vendor'],
   function($view){
    /* 
     * Somehow get that instance of the project 
     * that is already instantiated on the show page. And
     * send it to the component.      
     */
     $project = ; 
     $view->with(compact('project'));
   }
 );
```

So the desired outcome would just be able to call the following on a single project view and have that instantiated class passed into this component every time it is called. For example just:

```
@component('layouts.modals.add-project-vendor')

@endcomponent
```

Comment: `$project = $view["project"];` ... maybe

Comment: @apokryfos ding ding ding! So simple and works great! TYSM! Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's view implements `ArrayAccess` and does allow access to the passed variables via that.

In your case you can use:

```
$project = $view["project"];
```

This will access any parameter with name "project" passed to the view.

As a sidenote you can get all variables you passed as an associative array using `$view->getData()` in case you need it.

Comment: Just to quickly add to this, because the data is now being changed to the view composer, to clean up the blade template I can simply just use one line `@include('layouts.modals.add-project-vendor')`